# Streaming / Transcoding failed

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, encoding, suse

I installed VLC, and works well apparently, on Suse Linux Enterprise Desktop 11 SP3, but when I streamed some video (.flv format) I get this error.-

```
Streaming / Transcoding failed
VLC could not open the encoder
```

Note.- I'm using the VLC 1.1.13 The Luggage. I'll appreciate any help

Comment: We need more information to answer in a helpful way. It looks like you are trying to transcode something. A detailed error message would be helpful. Also, which format are you transcoding from/to?

Comment: Also, the current version of VLC is 2.1.3. Is there a reason why you're using such an old version?

Comment: @mkasberg Surfing on the WEB, only I found this commands.- [link](http://pastebin.com/YeNgs4nj).

The video format: .flv (`New Destination: RMTP/MPEG Transport Stream`; `Profile: Video-H.264 + AAC (MP4`)

Answer (score 10):

I forced strictness to -2 in FFMpeg options in advanced VLC options. It's under Tools>Preferences, then I click All under Show settings, click on Video codecs under Input / Codecs, then FFmpeg . So it's: Tools>Preferences>Video codecs>FFmpeg . Under FFmpeg I scroll down to under Encoding and I go to Strict standard compliance and I set it to -2

OR
Add
--sout-ffmpeg-strict=-2

to your command line. So no need to change it in the Gui

Comment: Too late, but thank you for the answer. It will help me in the future.