# VLC could not open the mp4a audio encoder

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player, video-conversion

I am attempting to use the Convert/Save feature of VLC to convert an mkv file to an mp4. (H.264 video with MPEG-4 AAC audio)

I get the following error:

> VLC could not open the mp4a audio encoder

How can I remedy this? VLC 2.2.4 on Windows 10.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any more information you could provide?  Any other debug/error messages?  VLC version?  Metadata of the video? What media codecs you have installed?  What OS are you running this on?  If you're running it on a Linux distro, would you be able to provide additional debug info by starting VLC from terminal?

Comment: I added "VLC 2.2.4 on Windows 10" to my question. I haven't installed any codecs manually.

Comment: Would you also be able to add the commands/process you're using to get the error message?  Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: @ServiceManager Open UI -> Convert/Save. No other errors as VLC will continue to convert the video. However no audio track is saved.

Answer (score 27):

Go to Tools > Preferences > Input/Codecs > Video codecs > FFmpeg
 Changing the 'Strict standard compliance to -2 worked for me.

Found this method here:
[Streaming / Transcoding failed](https://superuser.com/questions/784115/streaming-transcoding-failed)

Comment: As dankohn noted below, you need to select "Show All at the bottom left" to show FFmpeg option

Comment: My problem was the video that I used VLC to convert, the convered MP4 was no audio, only video, I found that the audio format was not same with the original file format "MPEG-4 AAC" audio.You solution is works for me.

Comment: Like https://superuser.com/a/1233748/396998 answer says, you need to scroll down to find the `Strict standard compliance` section (doesn't always show an obvious scrollbar on a mac) - thanks @dankohn!

Answer (score 4):

On OS X, you select VLC menu and then Preferences. Then click Show All at the bottom left. Then under Video Codecs in the left pane, select FFmpeg, scroll halfway down and change `Strict standard compliance` to -2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open an mpeg4 video an alternative is to use the command below:

```
xdg-open test_video.mp4
```

If you get error, you might need to install the following in CentOS:

```
sudo yum install gstreamer gstreamer-ffmpeg gstreamer-plugins-bad gstreamer-plugins-bad-free gstreamer-plugins-bad-nonfree gstreamer-plugins-base gstreamer-plugins-good gstreamer-plugins-ugly gstreamer-plugin-crystalhd gstreamer1-plugins-bad-freeworld gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free gstreamer1-plugins-good gstreamer1-libav ffmpeg
```