# VLC media player Error while adding audio file to video

Tags: vlc-media-player, error-correction

[image]

What's wrong?

How can I fix that?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer]. Do not use images to post code or error message unless the image is conveying something more than the code or error message. If you need to you should augment the image with the text it contains because images of text are not searchable, accessible, and they make it harder for people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools > Preferences > Input/Codecs > Video codecs > FFmpeg and change Strict standard compliance to -2. Method from [Streaming / Transcoding failed](https://superuser.com/questions/784115/streaming-transcoding-failed)